# rake aborted! LoadError: no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/explain_pretty_printer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, activerecord

I have started learning Ruby on Rails, and i have followed many guides therefore i have work with many versions of Ruby om my Windows 7 64bit machine. At the moment i have Ruby 2.3 installed which i also used for Get Started Guide [Getting started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). Having Heroku i my mind for production. I have work through their [Getting started on Heroku with Ruby(Windows)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-jruby)  This also got me to install JRuby 9.1.8.I had huge success following the guide. I could test my app locally and on Heroku.
Having gone this while with the docs, I want to do a real life stuff here with Aptana v3  and creating an app the would be deployed on Heroku, I need to have my PostgreSQL server running which i have installed the Enterprise version 9.3. I tested it and i works fine.
Now i should be able to create my first project for heroku and i found another guide to that [Using Rails, Aptana, PostgreSQL, and Heroku Seamlessly](http://kendrickcoleman.com/index.php/Tech-Blog/using-rails-aptana-postgresql-and-heroku-seamlessly.html) 
Where i got stuck is while trying to create a postgres database.
I have decide to outline all steps taken to make thing clear.

When i run this command:) rails new readlyme-test-perfect -d postgresql
I got the following output:

```
Expected string default value for '--rc'; got false (boolean)
  create
  create  README.rdoc
  create  Rakefile
  create  config.ru
  create  .gitignore
  create  Gemfile
  create  app
  create  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
  create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
  create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
  create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
  create  app/assets/images/.keep
  create  app/mailers/.keep
  create  app/models/.keep
  create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
  create  app/models/concerns/.keep
  create  bin
  create  bin/bundle
  create  bin/rails
  create  bin/rake
  create  bin/setup
  create  config
  create  config/routes.rb
  create  config/application.rb
  create  config/environment.rb
  create  config/secrets.yml
  create  config/environments
  create  config/environments/development.rb
  create  config/environments/production.rb
  create  config/environments/test.rb
  create  config/initializers
  create  config/initializers/assets.rb
  create  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
  create  config/initializers/cookies_serializer.rb
  create  config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
  create  config/initializers/inflections.rb
  create  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
  create  config/initializers/session_store.rb
  create  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
  create  config/locales
  create  config/locales/en.yml
  create  config/boot.rb
  create  config/database.yml
  create  db
  create  db/seeds.rb
  create  lib
  create  lib/tasks
  create  lib/tasks/.keep
  create  lib/assets
  create  lib/assets/.keep
  create  log
  create  log/.keep
  create  public
  create  public/404.html
  create  public/422.html
  create  public/500.html
  create  public/favicon.ico
  create  public/robots.txt
  create  test/fixtures
  create  test/fixtures/.keep
  create  test/controllers
  create  test/controllers/.keep
  create  test/mailers
  create  test/mailers/.keep
  create  test/models
  create  test/models/.keep
  create  test/helpers
  create  test/helpers/.keep
  create  test/integration
  create  test/integration/.keep
  create  test/test_helper.rb
  create  tmp/cache
  create  tmp/cache/assets
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts
  create  vendor/assets/javascripts/.keep
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets
  create  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.keep
     run  bundle install

  Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
  Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

  Resolving dependencies...............................................................................................

  Fetching rake 12.3.1
  Installing rake 12.3.1
  Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.0.5 (java)
  Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5 (java)
  Fetching i18n 0.9.5
  Installing i18n 0.9.5
  Using json 1.8.6 (java)
  Fetching minitest 5.11.3
  Installing minitest 5.11.3
  Using thread_safe 0.3.6 (java)
  Fetching tzinfo 1.2.5
  Installing tzinfo 1.2.5
  Using activesupport 4.2.4
  Using builder 3.2.3
  Using erubis 2.7.0
  Fetching nokogiri 1.8.2 (java)
  Installing nokogiri 1.8.2 (java)
  Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
  Fetching rails-dom-testing 1.0.9
  Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.9
  Fetching crass 1.0.3
  Installing crass 1.0.3
  Fetching loofah 2.2.1
  Installing loofah 2.2.1
  Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
  Using actionview 4.2.4
  Fetching rack 1.6.9
  Installing rack 1.6.9
  Using rack-test 0.6.3
  Using actionpack 4.2.4
  Fetching globalid 0.4.1
  Installing globalid 0.4.1
  Using activejob 4.2.4
  Fetching mini_mime 1.0.0
  Installing mini_mime 1.0.0
  Fetching mail 2.7.0
  Installing mail 2.7.0
  Using actionmailer 4.2.4
  Using activemodel 4.2.4
  Using arel 6.0.4
  Using activerecord 4.2.4
  Fetching activerecord-jdbc-adapter 50.0
  Installing activerecord-jdbc-adapter 50.0
  Fetching jdbc-postgres 42.1.4
  Installing jdbc-postgres 42.1.4
  Fetching activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter 50.0
  Installing activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter 50.0
  Using bundler 1.16.1
  Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
  Using execjs 2.7.0
  Using coffee-script 2.4.1
  Fetching thor 0.20.0
  Installing thor 0.20.0
  Using railties 4.2.4
  Fetching coffee-rails 4.1.1
  Installing coffee-rails 4.1.1
  Fetching ffi 1.9.23 (java)
  Installing ffi 1.9.23 (java)
  Fetching multi_json 1.13.1
  Installing multi_json 1.13.1
  Fetching jbuilder 2.7.0
  Installing jbuilder 2.7.0
  Using jquery-rails 4.3.1
  Fetching sprockets 3.7.1
  Installing sprockets 3.7.1
  Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.1
  Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.1
  Using rails 4.2.4
  Fetching rb-fsevent 0.10.3
  Installing rb-fsevent 0.10.3
  Fetching rb-inotify 0.9.10
  Installing rb-inotify 0.9.10
  Using rdoc 4.3.0
  Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
  Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
  Fetching sass 3.5.5
  Installing sass 3.5.5
  Fetching tilt 2.0.8
  Installing tilt 2.0.8
  Fetching sass-rails 5.0.7
  Installing sass-rails 5.0.7
  Using sdoc 0.4.2
  Fetching therubyrhino_jar 1.7.6
  Installing therubyrhino_jar 1.7.6
  Fetching therubyrhino 2.0.4
  Installing therubyrhino 2.0.4
  Fetching turbolinks-source 5.1.0
  Installing turbolinks-source 5.1.0
  Fetching turbolinks 5.1.0
  Installing turbolinks 5.1.0
  Fetching tzinfo-data 1.2018.3
  Installing tzinfo-data 1.2018.3
  Fetching uglifier 4.1.8
  Installing uglifier 4.1.8
  Bundle complete! 11 Gemfile dependencies, 59 gems now installed.
  Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

To create a database i navigate to the project folder and i run this command:

```
rake db:create:all
```

I got this error:

```
$ rake db:create:all
rake aborted!
LoadError: no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/explain_pretty_printer
C:/Users/Luke/Documents/Aptana/readlyme-test-perfect/config/application.rb:7:in `(root)'
C:/Users/Luke/Documents/Aptana/readlyme-test-perfect/rakefile:1:in `block in (root)'
C:/Users/Luke/Documents/Aptana/readlyme-test-perfect/rakefile:4:in `(root)'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I need help please. Thank you.

Comment: did you make sure in your Gemfile `gem 'pg'` and then run `bundle install` ?

Comment: As you said, tried gem 'pg' or gem pg, i got the same error: $ gem pg
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError) Unknown Command pg

Comment: there is no command `gem pg` but the gem should be in your Gemfile.  Are you able to run `bundle install` ?

Comment: The bundle install command ran automatically after the scaffolding, as you can see from the post. However i tried running it again but no success. @alassandrocb puts the gem uninstall/install pg comand  which i did but i got another error. you can check it bellow. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you installed the postgresql gem before running this `rails new readlyme-test-perfect -d postgresq` ? Try reinstalling it.

```
gem uninstall pg
gem install pg
```

Comment: After running the uninstall command i did the install and got  errors:
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/jruby-9.1.8.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/pg-1.0.0/ext
C:/jruby-9.1.8.0/bin/jruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180321-8296-zr3nxl.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... RuntimeError: The compiler failed to generate an executable file.
You have to install development tools first.

Comment: Try with the directory postgresql is installed `gem install pg -- --with-pg-dir="C:\Path\To\PostgreSQL\9.5"`

Comment: gem install pg -- --with-pg-dir="C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3" I got the same error. I am suspecting, it could be something that requires building native  extension in C. I had similar issue while working with sqlite3 , but don't know what to do here with postgresql

Comment: @user3673744 Could you please edit your question with the new error output entirely.

Answer (score 1):

After following a lot of similar questions and their answers, i realized the cause of my problem was from the Ruby Installations. Though i was following the official documentation on Rails  and Heroku but running JRuby 9.1.8.I and Ruby2.3 was not a good one. With Ruby2.3 and Devkit i was able to install rails and could use slite3 and mysql adapters conveniently. Little did i know that it will also serve for postgresql. As i installed JRuby, it override the Ruby rails installation and could create a rails project like the one i posted issues from here.

To solve this problem, i simply uninstall the JRuby, remove it from environment variables  and after system restart, i install rails and created a rail projects with this command: rails new **readlyme-test-perfect -d postgresql** every thing works like charm. 
Right now with the help of this [Heroku Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5) i have got my application deployed in heroku, migrate my database and now coding conveniently from  Aptana3.

My big thank you goes to all my contributors.

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to stay on JRuby (the OP apparently switched back to C Ruby), I was able to get this to work by forcing an older version in my Gemfile:

`gem "activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter", "1.3.24", :platform => :jruby`

The versions >= 50.0 that were being pulled down automatically were conflicting with the versions of other dependencies (like Rails 4.2.8)